# How to add Testimonials slider to word press theme as existing theme doesn't have slider

Tags: wordpress

I have  intalled word press theme evrything working fine but Sir i need to add **Testimonials Slider to the existing section .**

Comment: Please Sir anyone Help me

Comment: Just look for plugins which do that

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using a plugin like this one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/testimonial-slider-and-showcase/

It seems pretty easy to set up.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, i have tried in local Wamp sever its working but in live server i have added same slider inside wp-content inside plugin floder but that plugin is not showing in Dashboard. If am installing the same plugin it is asking FTP Server Credetials actually  FTP Server password not Set.

Comment: Please Sir anyone Help me

Answer (score 0):

Hi everyone i found the solution for above problem which i mentioned 
 https://wordpress.org/plugins/testimonial-slider-and-showcase/

Step1:Need to create new Tetimonilas in Dashbord 
Step2: Generate Shortcut Code .
Step3: Instead of creating new page and pasting the ShortCut code  Go to existing page and add the code in which place you need to add slider.

Thank you Very Much idoric Sir & Johannes Sir